# Javascript: Setting checked=false is not removing checkmark from the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox that is embedded inside a div as depicted in the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="ms-Checkbox is-checked is-enabled root-751">
        <input type="checkbox" data-automation-id="ProductSkuId_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" class="input-521" id="checkbox-886" aria-label="Office 365 E1" aria-describedby="LicenseSubText_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" aria-checked="true" value="18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" checked="">
            <label class="ms-Checkbox-label label-738" for="checkbox-886">
                <div class="ms-Checkbox-checkbox checkbox-752">
                    <i data-icon-name="CheckMark" aria-hidden="true" class="ms-Checkbox-checkmark checkmark-754"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="css-742">
                    <div class="css-743" data-automation-id="LicenseText_Office 365 E1">Office 365 E1</div>
                </div>
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="css-736" id="LicenseSubText_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" data-automation-id="LicenseSubText_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e">
        <div class="css-735">‎12‎ of ‎591‎ licenses available</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As we can see from the above, there is an input of type "checkbox" and if I use the following javascript:

```
$("#checkbox-886").prop('checked', false);
```

The box is still checked. I have also tried the following:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox-886").removeAttribute("checked")
```

and it is still not removing the checkmark from the checkbox although i see that checked attribute has been removed from the input.

I am guessing that the div surrounding the checkbox is also responsible because i see the "is-checked" attribute and I am not sure how to write javascript that would force changes on the parent elements when the child element is changed through javascript. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, are you using any plugin  ?

Comment: Your code, *as provided* works fine.   https://jsfiddle.net/5uo48206/   It's most likely you have some other "wrapper" around the checkbox (3rd party plugin) that is replacing the checkbox with its own representation (maybe an image, probably this: `<i data-icon-class="ms-Checkbox-checkmark checkmark-754">`) and some css to hide the actual checkbox.   You need to use your plugin's API to change the state.   Or remove the plugin.   Or at the very least, tell us what it is!

Answer (score 0):

The element probably hasn't been loaded when you tried to uncheck it. Add an event listener to `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("checkbox-886").checked = false
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="ms-Checkbox is-checked is-enabled root-751">
    <input type="checkbox" data-automation-id="ProductSkuId_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" class="input-521" id="checkbox-886" aria-label="Office 365 E1" aria-describedby="LicenseSubText_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" aria-checked="true" value="18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e"
      checked="">
    <label class="ms-Checkbox-label label-738" for="checkbox-886">
                <div class="ms-Checkbox-checkbox checkbox-752">
                    <i data-icon-name="CheckMark" aria-hidden="true" class="ms-Checkbox-checkmark checkmark-754"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="css-742">
                    <div class="css-743" data-automation-id="LicenseText_Office 365 E1">Office 365 E1</div>
                </div>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="css-736" id="LicenseSubText_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" data-automation-id="LicenseSubText_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e">
    <div class="css-735">‎12‎ of ‎591‎ licenses available</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that and unfortunately, it is still not removing the checkmark from the box

Comment: @Spectre I have tried using this method but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please remove  checked="" from your control(<input  type="checkbox" data-automation-id)

If you want to check your checkbox then do it from java script only.

So, your code will be like

```
<div>
    <div class="ms-Checkbox is-checked is-enabled root-751">
        <input type="checkbox" data-automation-id="ProductSkuId_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" class="input-521" id="checkbox-886" aria-label="Office 365 E1" aria-describedby="LicenseSubText_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" aria-checked="true" value="18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e">
           <label class="ms-Checkbox-label label-738" for="checkbox-886">
                <div class="ms-Checkbox-checkbox checkbox-752">
                    <i data-icon-name="CheckMark" aria-hidden="true" class="ms-Checkbox-checkmark checkmark-754"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="css-742">
                    <div class="css-743" data-automation-id="LicenseText_Office 365 E1">Office 365 E1</div>
                </div>
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="css-736" id="LicenseSubText_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e" data-automation-id="LicenseSubText_18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e">
        <div class="css-735">‎12‎ of ‎591‎ licenses available</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript will be

```
document.getElementById("checkbox-886").checked=false;
```

Comment: *If you want to check your checkbox then do it from java script[sic] only* - sorry, but this is a terrible idea.  The page should be initiated at render time to reduce FOUC - the last thing you want it load a page then a few seconds later (when it's finished loading/parsing everything) suddenly all the tickboxes get ticked by themselves.  That's  just nasty UX.

Comment: ok..but your problem will be solved by removing attribute checked.

Comment: *How* will this solve the problem?  OPs code, *as provided*, already works as it is, so if you remove it go "see, it works" that means nothing, because it worked without removing it and there's no way to know if it works for unresponsive OP in their *actual* scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Remove checked = "" from input tag.
Then the javascript will work correctly.

```
$("#checkbox-886").prop('checked', false);
```